# API Platform add filter and pagination on non entity resource

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

For a route versionning and a better separation between the entity and the api output I made a resource that is not an entity linked to that entity by a provider.
A had like to add some filters and make a pagination but it seems I can't natively.

I have for example an entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserApiKeyRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Blameable\Traits\BlameableEntity;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: TreasureRepository::class)]
#[Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName: 'deletedAt', timeAware: true, hardDelete: false)]
class Treasure
{
use BlameableEntity;

use TimestampableEntity;

#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
#[ORM\Column]
private int $id;

#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'treasures')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName: 'owner_id', nullable: false)]
private Owner $owner;

#[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
private string $name;

#[ORM\Column(type: Types::DECIMAL, precision: 10, scale: 2)]
private string $value;

#[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
private ?\DateTimeInterface $deletedAt = null;
```

I made a resource:

```
<?php

namespace App\ApiResource\V1;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Delete;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Link;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post;
use App\Entity\Owner;

#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/owners/{owner_id}/treasures/{id}.{_format}',
    shortName: 'Treasures',
    operations: [
        new Get(),
        new Delete(
            processor: TreasureProcessor::class
        )
    ],
    uriVariables: [
        'owner_id' => new Link(
            fromProperty: 'treasures',
            fromClass: Owner::class
        ),
        'id' => new Link(
            fromClass: self::class
        )
    ],
    provider: TreasureProvider::class
)]
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/owners/{owner_id}/treasures.{_format}',
    shortName: 'Treasures',
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(
            normalizationContext: ['groups' => 'list']
        ),
        new Post(
            denormalizationContext: ['groups' => 'create'],
            processor: TreasureProcessor::class,
        )
    ],
    uriVariables: [
        'owner_id' => new Link(
            fromProperty: 'treasures',
            fromClass: Owner::class
        )
    ],
    provider: TreasureProvider::class
)]
class TreasureResource
{
    #[Groups(['list'])]
    private ?int $id;
    #[Groups(['list', 'create'])]
    private string $name;
    #[Groups(['list', 'create'])]
    private string $value;
    private ?Owner $owner;

    public function __construct(
        string $name,
        string $value,
        ?Owner $owner = null,
        ?int $id = null
    )
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->owner = $owner;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getValue(): string
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function getOwner(): ?Owner
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }
}
```

Like that I do not have pagination neither filters.
If I add the filter attribute on name for example

```
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, strategy: 'partial')]
```

I have an error

> Call to a member function getClassMetadata() on null

Also, I tried to add a pagination into my Provider that is not working well, I do not have the real result of "hydra:totalItems" that show the total of the current page and not all the results, and I do not have the previous, next, total pages informations provided by json-ld.
I did not see a way to set the ApiPlatform pagination with data.

Here is a sample of my provider:

```
$owner = $this->ownerRepository->find($uriVariables['owner_id']);

/** ApiPlatform\State\Pagination\Pagination $this->pagination */
$page = $this->pagination->getPage($context);
$itemsPerPage = $this->pagination->getLimit($operation, $context);

$treasures = $this->treasureRepository->findByOwnerPaginated($owner, $page, $itemsPerPage);

return $this->collectionToResources($treasures); //returns an array
```

Anyone ran into theses issue and were able to solve or bypass them? I wish I could use ApiPlatform attributes out of the box even with this way of coding

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and I found it's now available since v3.1.8. To achieve it you've to use the `stateOptions`:

```
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(
            uriTemplate: '/entityClassAndCustomProviderResources/{id}',
            uriVariables: ['id']
        ),
        new GetCollection(
            uriTemplate: '/entityClassAndCustomProviderResources'
        ),
    ],
    provider: EntityClassAndCustomProviderResourceProvider::class,
    stateOptions: new Options(entityClass: SeparatedEntity::class)
)]
class EntityClassAndCustomProviderResource
```

Source code: https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/5550/files#diff-15a5e5dac807773e03253202f2a43d4e695aa7ac2f43874116741a6d9b4c69ca